# Error: [only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars] when changing variable order

Tags: python, function, scipy

Dear Stackoverflow Community,

I am very new to Python and to programming in general, so please don't get mad when I don't get your answers and ask again.

I am trying to fit a curve to experimental data with scipy.optimization.curve_fit. This is my code:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as nm
from __future__ import division
import cantera as ct
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages
import math as ma
import scipy.optimize as so


R = 8.314
T = nm.array([700, 900, 1100, 1300, 1400, 1500, 1600, 1700])
k = nm.array([289, 25695, 763059, 6358040, 14623536, 30098925, 56605969, 98832907])


def func(A, E, T):
    return A*ma.exp(-E/(R*T))
popt, pcov = so.curve_fit(func, T, k)
```

Now this code works for me, but if I change the function to:

```
def func(T, A, E)
```

and keep the rest I get:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Also I am not really convinced by the Parameter solution of the first one.
Can anyone tell me what happens when you change the variable order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wonder whether you data shows an exponential decay of rate. The mathematical model may not be the most suitable one.

[image]See the doc string of `curve_fit`

> f : callable
>   The model function, f(x, ...). It must take the independent variable as the first argument and the parameters to fit as separate remaining arguments.

since your formula is essentially: `k=A*ma.exp(-E/(R*T))`, the right order of parameters in `func` should be `(T, A, E)` or `(T, E, A)`.

Regarding the order of `A` and `E`, they don't really matter. If you flip them, the result will get flipped as well:

```
>>> def func(T, A, E):
    return A*ma.exp(-E/(R*T))

>>> so.curve_fit(func, T, k)
(array([  8.21449078e+00,  -5.86499656e+04]), array([[  6.07720215e+09,   4.31864058e+12],
       [  4.31864058e+12,   3.07102992e+15]]))
>>> def func(T, E, A):
    return A*ma.exp(-E/(R*T))

>>> so.curve_fit(func, T, k)
(array([ -5.86499656e+04,   8.21449078e+00]), array([[  3.07102992e+15,   4.31864058e+12],
       [  4.31864058e+12,   6.07720215e+09]]))
```

I didn't get your `typeerror` at all.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the fact that the independant variable must be the first argument makes sense. I changed that. Funny thing is I get the typeerror as soon as I do that. Now I changed the function to:
    k = A * nm.exp(-E/(R*T))

And everything goes flawless. No clue what the reason for that is but it works now. Thank you

Comment: But the curve I get completely misses the original data :/

Comment: `exp` in `math` does not support boardcasting, which should result that `TypeError`. Why I didn't get one is beyond me. `numpy` boardcasting is very handy, you just manipulate `arrays` as if they are scalars. Regarding the fit result, shouldn't exponential decay equation actually decay (rate of increasing slows down)? Your 'k' certainly is increasing and has positive 2nd derivative as well. I guess you probably shouldn't assume it to follow First-Order reaction rule.

Comment: Well it's supposed to go to infinity pretty fast. I don't know why this doesn't work with scipy. I solved the problem with taking the logarithm of everything, what makes my k a linear function which is probably easier to fit.
Anyway, Thank you very much for your help, if I had enough reputation I would definitely vote you up, sorry for that.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem and found the cause and its solution:
The problem lies on the implementation of Scipy. After the optimal parameter has been found, Scipy calls your function with the input array `xdata` as first argument. That is, it calls `func(xdata, *args)`, and the function complains with a type error because `xdata` is not an scalar. For example:

```
from math import erf
erf([1, 2]) # TypeError
erf(np.array([1, 2])) # TypeError
```

To avoid the error, you can add custom code for supporting arrays, or better, as suggested in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55497719/3671939) of Joris, use numpy functions  because they have support for scalars and arrays.

If the math function is not in numpy , like `erf` or any custom function you coded, then I recommend you instead of doing `from math import erf`, to do as follows:

```
from math import erf as math_erf # only supports scalars
import numpy as np
erf = np.vectorize(math_erf) # adds array support

def fit_func(t,s):
    return 0.5*(1.0-erf(t/(np.sqrt(2)*s)))

X = np.linspace(-5,5,1000)
Y = np.array([fit_func(x,1) for x in X])
curve_fit(fit_func, X, Y)
```

Answer (score 2):

The curve_fit function from scipy does not handle very well embedded functions from the math module. When you change the exponential function to the numpy exponential function you don't get the error:

```
def func(A, E, T):
    return A*np.exp(-E/(R*T))
```